# What is a nonnegative complex number?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I'm reading Linear Algebra by Axler, and he states in page 225 that «a complex number is nonnegative iff it has a nonnegative square root».

What does the author mean by this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Usually nonnegative complex numbers are simply the nonnegative reals inside $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Worded another way, when looking at complex numbers in polar form, the non-negative numbers are zero or those with argument (*angle*) equal to zero.  Indeed, if you take any number with nonzero argument and square root it, you in effect half the argument (*or half it and add $\pi$*) and it will again be nonzero.

Comment: @Epsilon Thanks ;)

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I have Axler's book, I can't find that quote. Can you please give chapter, section...? As far as I can see, to mention "non-negative complex number" is, at least, misleading and confusing, and maybe even plain incorrect.

Comment: @DonAntonio is the 3rd edition. page 225